# rest api are too slow after ssl

Tags: rest-api, magento-2.1.7, ssl

I'm building rest api for mobile application and it was working fine and result was returned in 3 seconds at most.
Two days ago I added ssl to my server and since then it takes about 10 to 13 seconds to return result.

and on time it returned result in 14 minutes.

what are causes of that?

**Note:** I've also tried search criteria api and it takes 5 minutes